# How do I add all items in an ObservableCollection to an Entity Framework table?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding, datagrid

I am biding the `ItemsSource` property of a `DataGrid` to an Entity Framework table as such:

```
_displayItems = new ObservableCollection<DISPLAY_ITEM>(_displayMaster.DISPLAY_ITEM);

public ObservableCollection<DISPLAY_ITEM> DisplayItems
        {
            get
            {
                return _displayItems;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_displayItems != value)
                {
                    _displayItems = value;
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayItems"));
                }
            }
        }
```

where `_displayMaster` is an Entity Framework table (`DISPLAY_MASTER`) with a foreign key reference to `DISPLAY_ITEM`.

My `DataGrid` is editable, users can edit, add, or delete values. These changes are then reflected in the `ObservableCollection`. The problem I am having is understanding how to take what is in the `ObservableCollection` and having that reflected in the `DISPLAY_ITEM` Entity Framework object before saving changes to the context. I have tried simply saying:

`_displayMaster.DISPLAY_ITEM = _displayItems;`

This works, however when I go to validate changes using:

```
DbEntityValidationResult itemValidationResults = _context.Entry(_displayMaster.DISPLAY_ITEM).GetValidationResult();
```

I get an error saying the `ObservableCollection1` is not part of the model. If I skip validation and there are no errors it actually does save back fine, but I need validation. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: maybe try doing it AsEnumerable() ?

Comment: @TMan At which point are you recommending I use AsEnumerable()?